# Entity Framework IQueryable, with 2 queries

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, iqueryable

I wanted to ask if there is a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do.

I need to get all the records of a child graph that have the date greter or equal to the given date, and the first record with date minor to the given date.

I found this solution that works but I'm not sure that this will be the best way.

```
var q = context.Istc0.Include("Interests").Where(a => a.IIsin == listKey).Select(a => new
{
    Istc0 = a,
    Interests = a.Interests.Where(d => d.InDat >= date)
});

var qq = context.Istc0.Include("Interests").Where(a => a.IIsin == listKey).Select(a => new
{
    Istc0 = a,
    Interests = a.Interests.Where(d => d.InDat < date).OrderByDescending(d => d.InDat).Take(1)
});

var xxx = q.ToList()[0].Istc0;
xxx = qq.ToList()[0].Istc0;

return xxx;
```

Comment: It looks like you are executing the `q` query, and then throwing away the results.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're trying to do here.  Looking at your code you're just getting the `Istc0` property of the first result of q and then overwriting it with the `Istc0` property of the first result of qq.  Is there anything else you want to do?  The `Interests` properties of both queries don't seem to be used.

Comment: Ok I try to explain it better, I have to get all the records in my interest table from a date in the past until today, but I also need the first record before that day. I this way it works and I get all the data I need, but it doesn't seem a very clean way to do the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know which one you need to return. Probably yyy.

```
var q = context.Istc0.Include("Interests").Where(a => a.IIsin == listKey).Select(a => new
    {
        Istc0 = a,
        Interests = a.Interests.Where(d => d.InDat >= date)
    }).ToList();


var xxx = q[0].Istc0;
var yyy = q.OrderByDescending(d => d.InDat).Take(1).SingleOrDefault().Istc0;

Dictionary<string,decimal> result = new Dictionary<string,decimal>();

result.Add("all",xxx);
result.Add("previous",yyy);

return result;
```

In this example i create a Dictionary with a string key (could be an integer or whatever you like) and with a decimal(i am guessing the returned value is of decimal type) value to store the results of the queries. Then i return this dictionary.

Another way would be to have a strongly typed object and return a list of that object.

Lastly, you could define two output parameters ([read this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645764%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)). For instance:

```
public void GetInterestRates(string listKey, out decimal currentRate, out decimal previousRate)
{
    var q = context.Istc0.Include("Interests").Where(a => a.IIsin == listKey).Select(a => new
        {
            Istc0 = a,
            Interests = a.Interests.Where(d => d.InDat >= date)
        }).ToList();


    var currentRate = q[0].Istc0;
    var previousRate = q.OrderByDescending(d => d.InDat).Take(1).SingleOrDefault().Istc0;

}
```

And when you want to use this:

```
decimal currentRate , previousRate;
GetInterestRates(listKey, currentRate , previousRate);
```

Comment: I need the result of both queries. the first query has to return all interest rates that are greater or equal to the date I pass, and the second query return me the first interest rate which date is less than the date I pass

Comment: Hi, you may check some of the choises i have in my edited post.

Answer (score 0):

Hi thanks for the answer.

With the query you posted I don't get all the data I need. I don't think that I can get what I need with one query.

```
Interest table
-----------------
2013-5-16 | 1%
2013-6-21 | 0.8%
2013-7-12 | 0.5%
2013-8-06 | 0.6%
```

The istc0 table contains all my isin  number, and as a relationship with the interest table One to Many.

On of the parameter of the function is the date. so if I pass for example

date = 2013-7-01

the result I need is the following:

```
Interest table
-----------------
2013-6-21 | 0.8%
2013-7-12 | 0.5%
2013-8-06 | 0.6%
```

So in my forst post the first query assigned to q retrieves all the interests after july the first, the second query assigned to qq retrieves the first interest rate before july the first. 
My function does the job, and I get the set of data that I need, but it doesn't seem to be the cleanest way to do it.